# MS Access VBA outlook code for query output

Tags: ms-access

I have 3 queries. First query has  10 records, 2nd and 3 query has 1 each. The query fields are ID and Name. I want to write a msaccess query, so it opens all 3 queries and create the output in a outlook email as below:

So under name it should have 10+ names or less and ID from 1st query, then 1 record from 2nd query and then the 3rd. it should be in a table format. also it should not ignore duplicate.

```
Name    ID  
first    1  
second   2  
third    3  
fourth   4  
first    5
```

Comment: VBA procedure that opens and loops recordset(s) to concatenate data.

Comment: Please don't put the same text several times into your question. Instead of things like that, include the code you have done so far. And if you haven't tried anything, then you're here too early. StackOverflow is not a code writing service.